# Pandas: divide value of one matrix by another with respective subindex

Tags: pandas, matrix

I would like to divide each value of the matrix A with the value of matrix B if the sub-index of the A's value is the index of B.

Take a example:
A:

```
         (A, 1)    (A, 2)    (B, 1)    (B, 2)    (B, 3)
(A, 1)  0.102179  0.024903  0.598978  0.141483  0.904239
(A, 2)  0.563096  0.765552  0.608203  0.339500  0.671222
(B, 1)  0.867550  0.432277  0.311634  0.165246  0.046199
(B, 2)  0.813666  0.846750  0.145595  0.996221  0.209762
(B, 3)  0.834860  0.176203  0.886546  0.506550  0.883405
```

And B:

```
   (A, 1)    (A, 2)    (B, 1)    (B, 2)    (B, 3)
1  0.996778  0.801235  0.120127  0.863761  0.519856
2  0.757775  0.706402  0.428906  0.479940  0.001049
```

I would like for the first column of A:

```
         (A, 1)    
(A, 1)  0.102179/0.996778  
(A, 2)  0.563096/0.757775
(B, 1)  0.867550/0.996778
(B, 2)  0.813666/0.757775
(B, 3)  0.834860
```

Same idea for the other columns, e.g. the second one:

```
        (A, 2)
(A, 1)  0.024903/0.801235
(A, 2)  0.765552/0.706402
(B, 1)  0.432277/0.801235
(B, 2)  0.846750/0.706402
(B, 3)  0.176203
```

I was looking for in the group by approach in Panda, but I haven't find something right. Thanks you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.div.html):

```
df = df1.div(df2, level=1, fill_value=1)
print (df)
            A                   B                      
            1         2         1         2           3
A 1  0.102509  0.031081  4.986206  0.163799    1.739403
  2  0.743091  1.083734  1.418033  0.707380  639.868446
B 1  0.870354  0.539513  2.594204  0.191310    0.088869
  2  1.073757  1.198680  0.339457  2.075720  199.963775
  3  0.834860  0.176203  0.886546  0.506550    0.883405

print (0.102179/0.996778 )
0.10250928491599935
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. I found div, but I haven't understood the `fill_value` and every value with mismatch index becames NaN.

Comment: Glad can help you, nice day!